# should I install android virtual device or use mobile for debugging?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, android-virtual-device

I'm new android development. I need to choose a device to run my app. So that what is the best way. Somebody told me that ,AVD will slow down your Mac. 
( My android phone is Moto G4 Plus )
So Suggest me what should I choose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a real device go for the device. Unless try to install AVD.

Answer (score 2):

An AVD will have an impact on any computer, Mac or otherwise, because it takes quite a bit of RAM to emulate a device. 4 GB is the minimum recommended, but 8 GB would be better.

The real question here is how serious are you about getting your app tested on multiple devices? Can you guarantee that your app is simple enough and/or that your code is written well enough to be able to run smoothly on all devices? If not, test it on your phone *and* multiple AVDs, on multiple versions of Android.

The best type of testing is to do it on multiple real devices - it's the only way to factor in things like battery consumption, physical input and network issues. Of course, this will greatly increase your expenses when you're starting out but it will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: Thank you Ray. I'm going to use my real device.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for describing. This is should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on you.There is some difference between AVD and phone.You can choose different SDK API and dpi on AVD, it really convenience when you want to test your app on different mobile phone.But be sure your OS have enough RAM to run AVD or your system will be very slow.If you use your a mobile phone,you don't need to wait AVD to start up and safe your time(start up really slow for me at the first time).You also need to use your phone when your app use a mobile sensor and AVD don't have.Real phone could more operable.

Comment: Thank you Juce. I'm going to use my real device.